# the jupyter notebook looks like old version and can't open previous codes as cell, opens them as scripts?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel, jupyter-irkernel

when i open jupyter notebook using anaconda prompt this the web page it is opening. [Jupyter notebook on Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5AaO.png) i have uninstalled and installed anaconda 2 to3 times but everytime same result.i have updated all packages and also created multiple environments for jupyter in navigator.

Does anyone know about the solution for this type of problem?

Comment: You've got two questions there. You are asked in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to focus on one. Please after you get your answer about the interface, search for a solution or advice first and then post separately about not opening correctly. As to the interface, that is the correct current version of Jupyter Notebook 7 that you show. That's the document-oriented offering from the Jupyter project, read more about it [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/announcing-jupyter-notebook-7-8d6d66126dcf). If you want the more IDE-style interface, then you are ...

Comment: <continued> looking for JupyterLab. Read more about the most recent JupyterLab offered [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-4-0-is-here-388d05e03442), keeping in mind that the JupyterLab offered on the tiles available on Anaconda Navigator may not quite be that version yet. Anaconda base settings are more conservative and don't offer the cutting edge versions as part of the base. Only after some of the issues are worked out does Anaconda move towards including the versions and so they always lag a bit behind. You can opt in to whatever version you want though.